# How Do I set up Flex/AS3 Documents and environment in TextMate

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, textmate

I have been trying to find solutions to this everywhere and cannot find any concise, clear instructions on how to set up Flex and Actionscript properly on TextMate. That is, I have the bundles but in terms of setting shell environments etc so that you can compile with ANT, find documentation for keyword (Reference Doc) within the app. For the latter ,when i try and do that it says no documentation found.

My shell env stuff is as follows:

TM_FLEX_PATH   /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Burrito/sdks/flex_sdk_4.5.0.17689
  TM_FLASH_HELP  /Users/doronkatz/langRef (this is where i have the as doc zip file i downloaded)

Comment: When i go to documentation for word i get:
----
Flex SDK
Flex SDK language reference not found.
Search Livedocs

#

Answer (score 0):

The [actionscript3.tmbundle](https://github.com/simongregory/actionscript3-tmbundle) comes with a pretty extensive help. Here is the paragraph on documentation:

> Documentation is not included with the SDK so has to be installed separately for the documentation command to work. You can download it from [this](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/) page, or directly as a [zip file](http://www.adobe.com/go/flex_documentation_zip). Once downloaded please rename the unzipped directory "**docs**" and place it in your Flex SDK directory.

I was about to say that it doesn't support the Flex4 documentation but I noticed the author made some changes related to the documentation 12 hours ago, so… maybe you should try with the very latest version of the bundle.

I have these shell variables:

```
TM_FLEX_PATH                = /Developer/SDKs/flex_sdk_4.1.0.16076
TM_FLEX_BACKGROUND_TERMINAL = true
TM_FLEX_USE_FCSH            = true
```